# centos-6へのffmpegのインストールに関しまして

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

最初の問題は解決し現在、ffmpegでconfigureをすると以下のエラーが表示されます。いろいろと試しておりますが、解決策が見つかりません。どうかご教示頂けませんでしょうか。

```
[root@server-xxxxxx-x ffmpeg-2.2.2]# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/src/f2 --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/src/f2/include" --extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/src/f2/lib"

ERROR: libx264 must be installed and version must be >= 0.118.
```

行った作業は以下の通りです。

1. Yasm エラーなし
2. libx264 エラーなし
3. libfaac エラーなし
4. ffmpeg 上記のエラー

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

下記の問題は以下のサイトを参考にエラーが出なくなりました。

```
https://blog.hostonnet.com/error-we-got-while-doing-the-ffmpeg-installation-on-centos-7
```

お世話になっております。以下のサイトを参考にcentos-6にffmpegをインストールし、ffmpegのコマンドを試しましたがffmpegがインストールされていないという内容のメッセージが表示されました。

あれこれと試しておりますが、原因が分かりません。どうすれば宜しいか、ご教示頂けませんでしょうか。

http://n73.jugem.jp/?eid=65

上記サイトの2：libx264のmakeを実行すると以下に表示されているエラーが出ます。

> ```
> filters/video/resize.c:215: error: ‘AVComponentDescriptor’ has no member named ‘depth’
> ```

＊環境
OS：centos-6 (x86_64)
Plesk 17.0.17
ImageMagick-6.7.2.7-6.el6.x86_64
ImageMagick-devel
php-devel
PECL imagick

Comment: 参考にされたサイトの手順で`libx264`のダウンロードが`last_x264.tar.bz2`を指していますが、このファイル名はアクセスしたその時々で最新のファイル名に代わります。記事では`x264-snapshot-20140518-2245`と4年前のスナップショットなので最新版とはコンパイルの前提環境が異なっている可能性があります。まずは記事と同じ日付のファイルをダウンロードして試してみては如何でしょうか。

Comment: hinaloe様、ご教示感謝致します。日付の件は当初よりx264-snapshot-20180220-2245という様にダウンロードされた日付をそのまま使用致しました。いろいろと試しておりますが、他に何か試す方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: 「ffmpegがインストールされていないという内容のメッセージ」を省略せずに追記して頂けますか？また、make時のワーニングやエラーは他にありませんか？

Comment: take88様、ご連絡感謝致します。ImageMagickの[root@server-xxxxxxxx-x ~]# convert -list configure をすると次の結果になり、"DELEGATES bzlib fontconfig freetype gs jpeg jng jp2 lcms openexr png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib"  ImageMagickの専門家の見解でシステムにmpegがインストールされていない、つまりffmpegがインストールされていないということだそうです。

Comment: take88様、makeのエラーに関しましては、”libx264が存在しない”というようなエラーが度々出ておりましたが、その都度修正しておりました。この状態から修復可能であれば、その方向で行こうと思いますが、再インストールした方が早いのであれば、今回のcentOS6にffmpegをインストールする最新版のガイドなどをご紹介頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: `ImageMagick`が`ffmpeg`のインストールとの関連が不明ですが、本当に`ffmpeg`のインストールだけが今回の目的でしょうか。やろうとしている事の全体像を書いておいた方が回答の参考になるかと思います。また、`ffmpeg`のインストールに関してはソースコードからではなく、`yum`を使ったパッケージをインストールする方法も検索すると出てきますので参照してみては如何でしょうか。

Comment: cubick様、ご教示頂きまして感謝いたします。画像、動画などを編集できればというのが目的です。ffmpeg単体でも目的を実現可能かと思われますが、ImageMagickを実行した際にffmpegが必要とのことでした。どれを参考にすべきか全く分かりませんので、今回のcentos-6 (x86_64)に最適な最新版のインストールガイドなどをご紹介頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 初めの問題は追記で説明している様にエラーが出なくなりましたが、更に進むとffmpegのconfigureで次のエラーが出ます。ヒント、アイデア、ご教示お願い頂けませんでしょうか。 libx264 must be installed and version must be >= 0.118.